# Iterate over subcategories in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

In Jekyll, a post can have multiple categories.  For example, a recipe for spaghetti might have the categories `dinner` and `food`.  Is it possible--without plugins--to iterate over the other categories (different dinner times) of a category (food)?  For example, I want to generate the following page for the category `food`:

```
Dinner:
* Spaguetti
* Meatloaf

Breakfast
* Cheerios
* Oatmeal

Lunch
* BLT
```

Comment: schmmd, did you find a solution?  Post back here so others can see an answer to your question.  Maybe the latest Jekyll has made this easier.

Answer (score 0):

Like a lot of Jekyll work, the answer is to loop through stuff way more than you think you should :)

Just loop through all categories or tags or whatever for your entire site, and use an `if` tag to avoid outputting ones that this post doesn't have.

Then inside the loop body, loop through every post on your site, using `if` tags again to avoid outputting the ones that don't have the category.

Here's some code that will do it for tags, I think if you replace `tags` with `categories` it'll work the same.  I've lightly modified it from my own site, sorry if there's a typo or two:

```
{% for topic in site.tags | sort_by:topic order:ascending %}
    {% if topic == whatever_topic_you_have %}
        <section class="topic">
            <h1><a name="{{ topic }}">{{ topic }}</a></h1>
            {% for item in site.posts %}
                {% if item.tags contains topic %}
                    ...show your post/item here...
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </section>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried adopting this approach for multiple subcategories, but it seems catered to one category at a time. I've asked a follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237526/list-subcategories-in-githubpages) if you feel like checking it out.