# Jekyll: View all Folders & Subfolders as Category and Sub Category

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-theme

I am working on a Comic Site project based on https://github.com/chrisanthropic/comical-jekyll-theme.

I am lookin for a way to display: `comic->subcomics->episode->.jpg files`.

Currently the theme supports only viewing of `episode->.jpg files`.

> Tree Structure defined:

- Firstly I created a folder called '_category' at the root of the
  site.
- Created 3 new folder 'main-comic-1' 'main-comic-2' 'main-comic-3'.
- Under each main-comic folder there will be 'sub-comic-1'
  'sub-comic-2' folders.
- Under each sub-comic folder there will be 'episode-1' episode-2'
  folders.
- These episode folder will have respective .html files to display the
  comic images in grid view.
  Requirement:
  need to display like this:

  `root/
  └── _category/
  ├── main-comic-1
  │   ├── sub-comic-1
  │   │   ├── episode-1
  │   │   └── episode-2
  │   ├── sub-comic-2
  │       ├── episode-1
  │       └── episode-2
  ├── main-comic-2
  │   ├── sub-comic-1
  │   │   ├── episode-1
  │   │   └── episode-2`

> Help:

Which files do i need to edit / add new to acheive a category, sub-category, episode page view based on the number of folders present in '_category'

Answer (score 0):

I asked similar questions before:

- [Hierarchical Categories in GitHub Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38700154/873165)
- [List Subcategories in GitHub Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39237526/873165)

Those approaches will work, but honestly they felt a little messy. Eventually I went with a dumber approach of manually using a `where` to create my pages.

This code, which I put inside an include file, will find a post or category that matches a URL:

```
{% assign post = site.posts | where:"url", include.url | first %}
{% unless post %}
    {% assign post = site.pages | where:"url", include.url | first %}
{% endunless %}
// code for rendering link to post
```

Then I just call something like this whenever I want to show a link to a page:

```
{% include url-thumbnail.html url="/path/to/file/here" %}
```

I guess you should go with the first approaches if you have thousands of files, or the manual approach if you have a more manageable amount of files.